# Why do parentheses make a difference in this simple code

Tags: c++

When I add two parentheses in this float ,the output becomes zero.

```
int main()
{
    float a=12.00*(20/100);
    cout <<a<<endl;
}
```

If I remove the parentheses, the output will be 2.4
but if I kept it, the output will be zero . Why ???

Comment: TL;DR: `(20/100)` is integer division.  It will always be zero since the numerator is less than the denominator.

Comment: `20/100` is integer division and it produces an integer value (`0`).

Comment: You should otherwise write  `float a=12.00*(20.0/100);`

Comment: It seems to me that this question is about operator precedence and type promotion and not about integer divisiion.

Comment: [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Reopened. Yes, 20/100 is 0, but the question asks why the two different forms give different results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`12.00*20/100` is parsed as `(12.00*20)/100` and is evaluated:

- Since `12.00` contains a decimal point; it is a `double` with value 12.
- `20` is an `int` with value 20.
- In `12.00*20`, the `int` 20 is converted to `double`, yielding a `double` with value 20.
- Then the `double` values 12 and 20 are multiplied, producing a `double` value 240.
- Then `(12.00*20)/100` is dividing a `double` 240 by an `int` 100.
- The `int` 100 is converted to `double` 100.
- Then the `double` 240 is divided by the `double` 100, producing a `double` value of approximately 2.4 (exactly 2.399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375 when IEEE-754 binary64 is used).

In contrast, `12.00*(20/100)` is evaluated:

- `20` and `100` are both `int` values, so `20/100` is performed with `int` division. `int` division produces an `int` result with the fraction discarded. So the result is the `int` value 0.
- Then `12.00*(20/100)` is multiplying the `double` value 12 by the `int` value 0, which produces 0.

In summary, two things are at play:

- Given an expression `a*b/c` where the two operators `*` and `/` have otherwise equal precedence, they are structured to perform the left operation first. (This is the rule for multiplicative operators. Some operators, such as assignment, associate right-to-left.)
- Multiplications or divisions with `int` operands are done with `int` arithmetic, even if the overall expression contains `double` operands somewhere else. In multiplications with mixed `int` and `double` operands, the `int` operand is converted to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
float a=12.00*(20/100);
```

the term `(20/200)` is computed first before the result of that term is multiplied with `12.00`. That's because the parenthetical term has higher precedence than the multiplication operator. `20/100` is computed using integer division, which results in `0`.

When you use

```
float a=12.00*20/100;
```

The term `12.00*20/100` is evaluated as `(12.00*20)/100` since the multiplication operator and division operator have the order of precedence and they have left to right associativity. Those operations are performed by promoting `20` and `100` to `double`. Hence, you get the expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think one important thing worth mentioning here which is [highly recommended](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) in mordern C++, [Integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) and [Floating point Literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal).

As already mentioned in most answers, by default in C++ a numeric with no literals is referred as integer types. But in mordern C++ you can be specific about the type using floating point literals "f".

Thus, in this way you know how you can explicitly let compiler know what type of numericals you are tying to use and get your expected result.

In below case,  (20.0f/100.0f) is not refered as integer type any more, and here I'm explicitly specifying compiler to treat these numericals as floating point types.

(Remember even using 20.0 is by default treated as double types and not float types.)

Example, try this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto a = 12.0f * (20.0f/100.0f);
    std::cout <<a<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @engf-010 Are you sure?